# Integral form of $2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k-1)^2-1}{(2k-1)^4+(2k-1)^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

Being inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308343/find-sum-limits-k-text-odd-frac2k2-1k4k21), I've wondered if the infinite series below may be expressed as
an intregral. I'm very curious about that.

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k-1)^2-1}{(2k-1)^4+(2k-1)^2+1}$$

I'd appreciate your feedback here. How should I ponder over this case as a simple student?
Where should I start from and what techniques I need to think of? Thanks!

Comment: I finally solve it :)

Comment: @Cortizol: really???

Comment: I was thinking on my problem. I add answer (in my topic).

Comment: I'd also like to see if there is solution via integrals :)