# Sum this series $\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4}+\frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4}+\ldots$ upto $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

> Sum this series: $$\dfrac{1}{1+1^2+1^4}+\dfrac{2}{1+2^2+2^4}+\ldots$$ upto $n$ terms.

My approach:
$$(1-n^6)=(1-n^2)(1+n^2+n^4)\implies \dfrac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}=\dfrac{n(1-n^2)}{1-n^6}$$

So, the above series can be written as $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{i(1-i^2)}{1-i^6}$$

I suppose that this can now be converted into integration which I cannot apparently. Please help. It would be better if the solution is not based upon integration but algebra.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571973/evaluate-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracnn4n21 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304851/evaluate-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack2-1k4k21

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle1+n^2+n^4=(1+n^2)^2-n^2=(1+n+n^2)(1-n+n^2)$

$$\frac{2n}{1+n^2+n^4}=\frac{(1+n+n^2)-(1-n+n^2)}{(1+n+n^2)(1-n+n^2)}=\cdots$$

Again if $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac1{n^2-n+1}, f(n+1)=?$

So, we are dealing with a [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: @Hawk, First impression : for finite $n,$ definite integral won't work

Comment: Yes, I missed that, if it were for infinite limit, how would that work? And, are there some other way in which my approach would have worked out?

Comment: This is beautiful and elegant.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{\mathcal{R} \equiv \braces{r}}$ the set of *simple poles* of $\ds{\pars{z^{4} + z^{2} + 1}^{-1}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
{k \over k^{4} + k^{2} + 1} & =
\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}}{1 \over 4r^{3} + 2r}{k \over k - r}\ =\
\overbrace{\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}}{1 \over 4r^{3} + 2r}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\
+\
\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}}{r \over 4r^{3} + 2r}{1 \over k - r}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over k^{4} + k^{2} + 1}} & =
\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}}{r \over 4r^{3} + 2r}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 - r}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Also
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 - r} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1 - r} - {1 \over k + n + 1 - r}}
\\[3mm] & =
n\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + n + 1 - r}\pars{k + 1 - r}} =
\Psi\pars{n + 1 - r} - \Psi\pars{1 - r}
\end{align}
where $\Psi$ is the *Digamma function* and we used a [well known identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7.E6).

---

Then $\ds{\pars{~see\ expression\ \pars{1}~}}$
$$
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over k^{4} + k^{2} + 1}} =
\color{#f00}{\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}}{r \over 4r^{3} + 2r}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{n + 1 - r} - \Psi\pars{1 - r}}}
$$

> Note that the final result is expressed as a finite sum which only has *four terms*.