# Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$ and if it converges find the sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check whether the series converges or not. If yes, find the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$$

**My Efforts**

Observe $n^3<n^4+n^2+1$

$\therefore$
$\frac{1}{n^4+n^2+n+1}<\frac{1}{n^3}$ which further implies that $\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+n+1}<\frac{n}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we conclude by comparison test that the series converges.

I am not able to find the sum of this series? Any hints or directions will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449510/how-to-find-the-sum-of-the-sequence-frac111214-frac212224/449513#449513  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691109/sum-this-series-frac111214-frac212224-ldots-upto-n-terms

Comment: Also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304851/evaluate-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack2-1k4k21

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative since

$$\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}\sim \frac1{n^3}$$

we can conclude that the series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^3}$.

For the evaluation let consider

$$\frac{n}{n^{4}+n^{2}+1} = \frac{1}{2(n^{2}-n+1)}-\frac{1}{2(n^{2}+n+1)}$$

and use telescoping, indeed for $n=k+1$ we have $$\frac{1}{n^{2}-n+1}=\frac{1}{k^{2}+k+1}$$

and therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}-n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+n+1}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\left(1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}-n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+n+1}\right)=\frac12\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+n+1}\right)=\frac12$$

Comment: Yet again not answering the question.

Comment: @Did I've answered to the main part "Check whether the series converges or not" the other is trivially true by telescoping and the hint was already given. Anyway I've update that. Now you can remove your downvote. Thanks

Comment: @Did Thanks for your advice and your great effort to damage my reputation here with continuous personal attacks. Have a nice day. The [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) is always here, please read it sometimes.

Comment: No personal attack here, only demonstrated facts. You do not like facts? Your problem, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{n}{n^{4}+n^{2}+1} = \frac{1}{2(n^{2}-n+1)}-\frac{1}{2(n^{2}+n+1)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$n^4+n^2+1=n^4+2n^2+1-n^2=(n^2+1)^2-n^2=(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)$$

$$((n+1)^2-(n+1)+1)=(n^2+2n+1-n-1+1)=(n^2+n+1)$$